# How to create Gatsby Route not in config file but by programatically

Tags: gatsby

I am working on one Gatsby project.
There is the function of the creating room of discussion.
For example: if I create the new room  I want to have the new route like the below. (with unique room id)
https://www.discussion.com/room/d3e353
How can I create the route for that dynamically for Gatsby?
In Gatsby normal dynamic routing is done in Gatsby gatsby.node.js file. by createPage function.
But in this case I have to create new route in source files not in config files.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby is a static site generater. You cannot create real pages dynamically like `https://www.discussion.com/room/d3e353` on the fly i.e. on the server during user request. Use good old PHP, Node.js or NextJS for this.

There is an alternative way for Gatsby: Use React on the client and create a dynamic room there:

The URL would look like: `https://www.discussion.com/room#d3e353`

You create the `/room` page. In this room page, you let React create a dynamic page for the user. You use React to "hydrate" the page. Learn about it in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use reach router for this [reach-router](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reach-router-and-gatsby/) out of the box -
https://reach.tech/router/example/multiple-routers